# How to enable jumpToSlide in Rmd revealjs presentation?

Tags: r, r-markdown, reveal.js, presentation

I created a revealjs presentation in RMarkdown and want to enable the jumpToSlide feature described [here](https://revealjs.com/jump-to-slide/).
Is it generally possible to enable jumpToSlide in RMarkdown revealjs presentation? How?

Thank you!

Normally, pressing the G key would prompt the user to type any number and then the presentation jumps to the slide with this number.

This is a code example, which doesn't provide the jumpToSlide feature

````
---
title: "JumpToSlides?"
author: "VPA"
date: "2023-05-05"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    slideNumber: true
    jumpToSlide: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## Slide with R Output

```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
summary(cars)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
````